# VS 2010 C# Express - Intellisense not showing all options

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I am having a strange problem with IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2010 C# Express Edition: when it pops up to show me the list of suggestions, the list is missing valid options.

For example, say I want to add a "KeyDown" event handler to a control, I start typing "`someControl.K<Ctrl+Space>`", but the popup doesn't list the KeyDown event; actually, it does not contain *anything* starting with a K (not KeyPress or KeyUp either).

This is not so bad, since simply typing "KeyDown" by hand won't kill me, but it is highly irritating, especially when I am dealing with objects whose members I am not familiar with.

After all, one of the uses of IntelliSense is giving you a quick overview of what Methods/Properties/Fields/etc. the object has to offer - but if it leaves out some of them semi-randomly, that point is rather moot.

(By semi-randomly I mean that, while there does not seem to be any discernable pattern for which members are left out, at least it is consistent in that it is apparently always the same ones that are missing.)

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this phenomenon? A corrupt IntelliSense cache? Is there a way to purge that cache and force a rebuild?

Comment: Was it previously working, or have you only just installed Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to delete the <s>.sdf and</s> .suo files of your solution (after closing it) and then reopen it.

Also make sure that all Statement Completion options are checked and 'Hide advanced members' is unchecked (see picture).

[image]

Comment: @HansPassant: Right, so there is no sdf file. The rest of the information should still be valid though.

Comment: I don't exactly know what did it in the end, but after several tries of deleting stuff like the .suo file and the content of the temp folder, as well as restarting Visual Studio, it now seems to work again. Let's see for how long...